# Illegal Start of expression/not yet confident in coding help welcome

Tags: java, methods

I am just starting my second class in computer science. We are working on our first project using java for this semester. The 1st method in the project calls for a static method, that can calculate the bill of a college student depending on credits.

The main issue I am running across is an **illegal start of expression** with my private int and private double. We did 1 inclass example in which we privatized an int and double in a nonstatic method and it worked fine. Is there any difference in doing this static vs nonstatic, and if so what must I do to correct it?

```
public class MyLibrary
{
    public static double CalcFree (int c) throws creditException        //integer c to represent total credits
    {
        private int credits;
        private double bill;

        if ( c > 1 && c < 33)       //providing valid range of options for total number of credits

            c = credits;

        else

            new creditException ("Invalid number of credits.");

        if ( c > 12)
        {
            bill = credits * 110 + 50 + 20;
            return bill;
        }

        else
        {
            bill = credits * 110 + 50;
            return bill;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to stick to the Java Naming Conventions. Classes (e.g. `creditException`) must start with uppercase, method names (e.g. `CalcFree`) with lowercase. Also, you can drop the use of `bill`, because the calculation of the bill can returned directly: `return credits * 110 + 50;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are these two lines inside the `CalcFree (int c)` method:

```
private int credits;
private double bill;
```

**Remove** the `private` from both.

**Note:** `c = credits;` must be changed to `credits=c;` as TNT pointed out correctly.

You can specify access modifiers  for instance variables but **not** for local variables.

It's also a good practice to give to local variables a different name from the instance variables.

Comment: I edited the code displayed. There were no reason for the instance variables I believe. 

The local variables both had private removed, however it says the variables may have not been initialized. Any advice on this issue?

Comment: @Mathew Osman it's an advice not an issue. The compiler will initialize them at default value: int default to 0, double default to 0.0d

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
private int credits;
private double bill
```

to

```
int credits;
double bill
```

inside `CalcFree()` Because you can declare local variables in `CalcFree()` method and local variables cannot be `private/public/protected,` etc. but they can be `final`

Comment: I made the change, however it now says the variables might not have been initialized.

Comment: @MatthewOsman Switch `c = credits` to `credits = c`. The former way assigns the variable `credits`, which has not been given a value, to the variable `c`. The second way assigns a value to `credits`.

Comment: @TNT should I also change the code so that credit * 110 +50, and the other line = bill instead of having bill 1st?

Comment: @MatthewOsman No, the `=` operator assigns the value on the right to the variable on the left, meaning that variable `bill` is being given some value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize those two variables after removing private modifier.

```
int credits = 0;

double bill = 0;
```